# Explaining the entries in routing table

Tags: routing, ipv4, ip-address, lan, route

I would like to ask for help with explaining every particular entry in routing table. That is what I receive after calling *route print* in my PC, based on Windows:

[image]

So my understanding is:

1. **0.0.0.0** indicates default route,
2. **127.0.0.0/8** indicates whole network of loopback addresses,
3. **127.0.0.1** is loopback address for my device,
4. **127.255.255.255** is a broadcast address in network of loopback addresses. What is its use case?
5. **192.168.1.0/24** is my private network,
6. **192.168.1.15** is a IP address of my router,
7. **192.168.1.255** is a broadcast address in my private network,
8. **224.0.0.0** is some kind of multicast address - what is its purpose?
9. **255.255.255.255** is a global broadcasting address for whole network, including every subnet in my private network.

Another point - why do we have Netmask /32 for f.e. **192.168.1.15** instead of /24?

Could someone clarify my consternations and check my points, if I am right here?

Comment: Has any answer solved your question? Then please accept it or your question will keep popping up here forever. Please also consider voting for useful answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 127.255.255.255 is a broadcast address in network of loopback addresses. What is its use case?

Good question - it's a subnet, so it's got a directed broadcast address. I don't see a real use case.

> 192.168.1.15 is a IP address of my router

No, 192.168.1.15 is your local interface IP address. Your router's address is the gateway in the 0.0.0.0/0 route.

> 224.0.0.0 is some kind of multicast address - what is its purpose?

224.0.0.0/4 is the logical subnet for all multicast addresses. The routing entry says *on-link*, so it basically means *for multicast, just send out of this interface*.

> 255.255.255.255 is a global broadcasting address for whole network, including every subnet in my private network.

255.255.255.255 is the *limited* broadcast address which is only propagated within the single subnet of the interface that sent it. It is never routed to other subnets (unlike the *subnet directed* broadcast address 192.168.1.255 which *may* be routed from elsewhere, depending on router configuration).

> why do we have Netmask /32 for f.e. 192.168.1.15 instead of /24?

Since 192.168.1.15 is your local IP address, that entry allows looping packets back to the local IP stack instead of actually transmitting them.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Regarding the 255.255.255.255 netmask, I think you are reffering to loopback address.